# Remote MySQL Connection from localhost Codeigniter = Extremely SLOW

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter & LAMP stack (without the MySQL) on my localhost to connect to a remote MySQL database on my server. This configuration is for development purposes only.

**Problem:** It takes up to a minute for the entire page to load! Is there any way to make this connection faster?

Sometimes its so slow i even get the error:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Unable to select the specified database: x

Filename: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/x/third_party/MX/Loader.php

Line Number: 96
```

Comment: Make only 1 connection, and disable hostname resolving on the remote db. And of course, make sure you only query for the absolute minimum amount of data necessary.

Comment: What kind of internet connection? If you are on a business T1 or something it would probably not be an issue. But if you're using a residential cable or DSL connection, the ISP might deliberately throttle ports like 3306.

Comment: I am using a residential cable half way across the world. I notice a slower load time with remote SQL access when I'm in the same country US as the server, but its not this slow! Maybe the throttling explains why its so slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your app is very hard on the DB, it is very likely that reverse DNS resolution is the cause. Disable it on the remote server by adding `skip-name-resolve` to your `my.cnf`.

Also, note that even for simple queries, the roundtrip "across the world" may be 200 ms or even more, so it *only* takes 300 queries to spend a minute on networking, regardless of the complexity or amounts of data.

Comment: Current number of queries is about 5, definitely under 10. Takes a variable time 30-60sec for the page to load. Strange...

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message. The problem was that I didn't set the connection parametres correctly. Douoble-check your Database Server credentials in database.php . Make sure the hostname, username, password and database are correct.